# How to add light in SceneKit?

Tags: swiftui, scenekit

I have a file called `navigation.scn` that has 3 models `spaceship.usdz` `earth.usdz` and `moon.usdz`. I currently with my code cannot see either 3. I also have placed a camera where I want to see out off. Maybe I need to illuminate there?

Code:

```
struct SCNViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        let sceneView = SCNView()
        

        if let scene = SCNScene(named: "navigation.scn") {
            sceneView.scene = scene
        
            let lightNode = SCNNode()
            lightNode.light = SCNLight()
            lightNode.light!.type = .omni
            lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)

            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        }
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        
        return sceneView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        // Update code if needed
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SCNViewWrapper()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: simulator display]
[navigation.scn screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRLBf.jpg)

Comment: just for testing purposes: each sceneView usually has a property called: .autoenablesDefaultLighting - consider you to set that to true, to see, if lighting works. If you still see nothing on screen, there might be issue with the entire scene setup.